# updating text after getting firebase info

Tags: swift, firebase, textview

Hi all I am trying to update a label or textview in swift after I get info from Firebase. I am not using a table view.
The data seems to come through on the console but it doesn't update the label.

I understand that the view is probably being loaded before the info comes but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Below is my code and my function

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
    })

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        configurePost()
}


func configurePost() {
        DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let desc =  snapshotValue? ["desc"] as? String ?? ""

        self.descriptionLabel.text = desc
        self.makeLabel.text = desc
    })

}
```

[image]

Comment: make use of notificationcenter()

Comment: Hi @this.girish, I am fairly new to programming, could you elaborate?